# K nearest neighbors in Mathcad - what functions I can use?

Tags: knn, mathcad

I found the k nearest neighbours Mathcad implementation in M. Nixon's book but 'distance' and 'coord' functions don't work. How can I fix it? [mathcad implementation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BTV1Y.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

`coord` return position of minimal value in the `dist`. This function could be like that

[image: <code>match</code>]

`distance` - Hmm, I think that is something wrong here

[image: example from book]

because it should be something like that

[image: euclidian distance]

or some other distance between `test` and `i` element from the `data`